# Не отображается svg через use элемент

Tags: html, svg

Хочу загрузить элемент `svg` через `use` из внешнего файла

В теле `html` пишу

```
<div>
  <svg>
    <use xlink:href="qwe.svg#arrow"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

указываю путь до самого файла(qwe.svg) и индификатор. но не отображается

код svg

```
<svg>
  <g id="arrow">
    <polygon points="38.25,0 38.25,357 318.75,178.5" />
  </g>  
</svg>
```

Comment: В коде svg не хватает `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`

Answer (score 3):

- Сначала нужно обязательно добавить файл `qwe.svg`  в HTML с помощью
  тега `<object>`

  ```
  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="qwe.svg">
    Your  browser does not support SVG 
  </object>
  ```
- Далее в любом месте документа HTML вызываете иконку по `ID`.

  ```
  <div>
    <svg class="svg-icons"> 
      <use  xlink:href="qwe.svg#arrow"></use> 
    </svg>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: приём, с возвращением=)

Comment: @Arthur спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Для Node.js проблема в том, что файл SVG отдается в текстовом формате.
В серверной части для типов файлов надо прописать следующее:

```
var contentTypesByExtension = {
    '.html': "text/html",
    '.css':  "text/css",
    '.js':   "text/javascript",
    '.svg': "**image/svg+xml**"
  };
```